# KnockoutJS cannot perform value binding with select

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My ViewModel is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    vm = new poReceivingModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});

function poReceivingModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.order_id = ko.observable()
}
```

And my html is like this:

```
<select id="id_po" class="form-control" name="po" data-bind="value:order_id">
<option value="1">4323</option>
<option value="2">1234</option>
</select>

<h1 data-bind="value: order_id">It is</h1>
```

When I select option of the select the value is not being updated.
I checked the documentation and found value binding with options binding.
But in my case I only want value binding.
Please help me correct my mistake.

Comment: options are populated automatically from database ie <select> is for foreignkey. So i just want value of which is selected.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment after realizing that everything was working fine. Just added an answer

Comment: Using the `options`-binding on the `select` is not possible? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks good, you just need to use a different binding on the h1 element, you're probably wanting to use "text"

```
<select id="id_po" class="form-control" name="po" data-bind="value:order_id">
<option value="1">4323</option>
<option value="2">1234</option>
</select>

<h1 data-bind="text: order_id">It is</h1>
```